# Possible to combine multiple highlight groups in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I currently have a pattern being created for extraneous whitespaces in vim with:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * syn clear EOLWS | syn match EOLWS excludenl /\s\+\%#\@!$/
autocmd InsertLeave,BufReadPost * syn clear EOLWS | syn match EOLWS excludenl /\s\+$/
```

I am also using the Indent Guides plugin which sets the patterns `IndentGuidesOdd` and `IndentGuidesEven`.  What I would like is some way to AND the patterns with `EOLWS`. For example something like: `hi EOLWS & IndentGuidesOdd ctermbg=darkred` So that only things matching both of these patterns will be highlighted.

Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT:

Okay so based on benjifisher's answer I attempted the following command.  The basic idea of the following regex is that I want it to match all but the current line when I enter insert mode.  I'm trying to highlight extra whitespace, but not to do any whitespace highlighting on the current line.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * exe 'match ExtraWhitespace ' . '/\(\%<' . line(".") .  '\(\s\+\%#\@<!$\)\|\(\t\+\)\)\&\(\%>' . line(".") . '\(\s\+\%#\@<!$\)\|\(\t\+\)\)/'
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
Error detected while processing InsertEnter Auto commands for "*":
E867: (NFA) Unknown operator '\%('
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing InsertEnter Auto commands for "*":
E475: Invalid argument: \(\%<57\(\s\+\%#\@<!$\)\|\(\t\+\)\)\&\(\%>57\(\s\+\%#\@<!$\)\|\(\t\+\)\)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

**Here is my final solution as a plugin:
https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace**

Comment: You'll have to edit the regex pattern on one of them or make a new group so that it matches both (e.g. using the `\|` operator).

Comment: Standard rules of debugging apply.  Start with something simple that works, then build up to what you want.  You can get some clues from the error numbers:  `:help E867` and `:help E475`.  After a quick look, I see two problems:  `\%<57` and `\%>57` should both be followed by `l` (or `c` for column).  Are you sure you copied the error messages correctly?  I do not see `\%(` in your pattern, and my vim (still 7.3) does not have an entry for E867.  When you resolve the syntax errors, the second problem I noticed is that you are trying to match (before Line 57) AND (after Line 57).

Comment: Ah thank you!  I did forget the `l`, and yes I did intend to OR those rather than AND them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:syntax` command to define a syntax group and the `:highlight` command to specify how to display it.  (The short forms are `:sy` and `:hi`, but almost everyone spends an extra character for readability and uses `:syn`.)

As @Conner said in the comment, you will have to define a new group, for example

```
:syn match EOLWSIndentGuidesOdd ...
:hi EOLWSIndentGuidesOdd ctermbg=darkred
```

You cannot combine highlight groups like <strike>`:syn match EOLWSIndentGuidesOdd EOLWS & IndentGuidesOdd`</strike>, but you should be able to combine patterns using `\&` as in

```
:syn match EOLWSIndentGuidesOdd <pattern1>\&<pattern2>
```

(You may have to enclose your patterns in `\(...\)` if they contain multiple branches.)  This is getting complicated enough that I would wrap the `:syntax` commands in a function and then

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * call EOLWS('on')
```

Alternatively, you could define the syntax groups once and just change highlight groups through the autocommands.

```
:help :syntax
:help :highlight
:help /\(
:help /\%(
:help /\&
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried playing around with some things a bit, but I'm not having a lot of luck.  I added my most recent attempt to the OP.